# Using writerow() with individual numbers and a list

Tags: excel, csv, export

The following function takes a list and outputs each item as an individual cell in a spreadsheet. However, the last item within csvwriter.writerow() called latlist is an entire list. I need to take each item in that list an export it into separate cells on the same line that contains the other values being exported.

Any suggestions?

```
def writeToCSV(dataset):

 AnimalID = 0
 CellID = 1
 File = 2
 latency = 3
 Atten = 4
 latlist = 5




 csvWriter = csv.writer(open('dtnlat.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
 csvWriter.writerow(['AnimalID','CellID', 'File', 'type', 'attenuation','latlist'])
 for x in range(len(dataset)):
     csvWriter.writerow([dataset[x][AnimalID],dataset[x][CellID], dataset[x][File], dataset[x][latency], dataset[x][Atten], dataset[x][latlist]])
```

Comment: I assume the list is saved in the same csv-file, but in what way is its data structure different from the rest?

Comment: @Tom Yes. Each item in csvWriter.writerow pulls a single number. However 'latlist' pulls a list. In the output, I get a cell with each number, and then a  cell in the same row with a list inside it. I want each item in that list inside a separate cell.